# Error running ansible role ansible-hardening from OpenStack

Tags: ansible, openstack

The ansible role 'ansible-hardening' from OpenStack is throwing this error:

> ERROR! Error when evaluating variable in import path: {{ stig_version
>   }}stig/main.yml.
>
> When using static imports, ensure that any variables used in their
>   names are defined in vars/vars_files or extra-vars passed in from the
>   command line. Static imports cannot use variables from facts or
>   inventory sources like group or host vars.

It was working before. I can't say I did anything to break the role.
I'm running ansible 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 18.10 (client). The role is the latest version checked out today per OpenStack instructions on https://docs.openstack.org/ansible-hardening/latest/getting-started.html#installing-the-ansible-hardening-role
The version I had before - that has worked in the past was also broken, showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to apply to ansible 2.6.5. It doesn't occur in ansible 2.8.2.

The error seems to be related to the ansible variable `{{ stig_version }}` not being available for the file https://github.com/openstack/ansible-hardening/blame/979805c9043793ab644dddd02091d4dce5ab267c/tasks/main.yml#L55

The variable is set in `ansible-hardening/defaults/main.yml`, but according to the error message, this path is not included when running the module `import_tasks`. Blame data shows that the module `include_tasks` was purposefully replaced by `import_tasks`.

I tested reversing to `include_tasks` in tasks/main.yml and this fixes the error.

A quick fix, without changing anything in the role `ansible-hardening` code, is to set `stig_version` in the `vars:` section of your playbook:

```
vars:
  stig_version: rhel7
```

Although I was able to fix the error and move on, I still don't understand why it stopped working, since less than 2 months ago.

I'm posting this here in case it helps other people, as the GitHub repo doesn't have the Issues tab activated - I couldn't find any place related to the project where to submit a post.